# Вычислить фундаментальную матрицу изображения

Tags: python, c++, opencv

Необходимо вычислить фундаментальную матрицу изображения для стереопары. Применить функции cv::stereoCalibrate() или cv::findFundamentalMat() нет возможности, так как отсутствуют необходимые координаты для этого. Однако есть данные внутренних параметров камер и внешних (матрица поворота R и параллельного переноса T). Можно ли только исходя из этих данных вычислить фундаментальную матрицу. Она необходима для дальнейших расчётов эпиполярных линий.

Comment: Экстринсиков и интринсиков достаточно чтобы вычислить фундаментльную матрицу.

Comment: Можно так: берёте семь точек на экране первой камеры. Придумываете семь Z-координат. Делаете обратную проекцию в мир. Делаете проекцию из мира во вторую камеру. Получаете достаточно данных для калибровки.

Comment: Можно математику выписать на прямую, но обратная/прямая проекции выглядят как более простой и надёжный способ.

Comment: Можно обойтись без обратной проекции если есть способ выдумать семь точек в пространстве, которые буду видные в обеих камерах.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy

[ https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga91018d80e2a93ade37539f01e6f07de5 ]
Начал подробнее изучать, как работает  cv::stereoCalibrate(). Заметил, что можно вычислить существенную и фундаментальную матрицы исходя из матрицы поворота и вектора переноса. 
Я же правильно понимаю, что элементы матрицы 
`{{0, -T2, T1},
{T2, 0, -T0},
{-T1, T0, 0}}`
 это элементы их вектора переноса.

Comment: Да, верно. Можно попробовать вычислить фундаментальную матрицу напрямую.